# Layout (Position of Thumbnails)

Tags: fotorama

I would like to use Fotorama with Thumbnails on my webpage.

Is was looking at the coding but as it is rather complex I couldn't find what I need.

I would like to have the thumbnails in a separate div container and the pictures in another div container. This way I would be able to place them individually wherever I need them.

Is there a possibility to do so?